# How to execute cmd in admin mode using robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to add to the store the certificate

Robot code is

${result}   Run Process certutil -addstore "Root" "C:\Users\Desktop\xyz.crt" shell=True

log ${result.stdout}

output is 
Administrator permissions are needed to use the selected options.  Use an administrator command prompt to complete these tasks.
CertUtil: The requested operation requires elevation.

So I need to run the process using privileged mode how to achieve it using robot frmaework

Comment: What operating system are you running? Does this need to be cross platform? What happens if you run python as admin?

Answer (score 1):

Try this assuming only windows

```sh
${result} Run Process runas /noprofile /user:<account with admin> <program that needs admin e.g. certutil>
```